# How to fetch next unique row from a table of postgres

Tags: postgresql

suppose my table contains two columns "id" (Type is character varying(22)) and "time" (Type is timestamp without time zone).

now I have some data in the table as follows,

```
id        time
P001     2015-02-04 10:00:00
P002     2015-02-04 10:00:00
P003     2015-02-04 10:00:00
P004     2015-02-04 10:10:00
P005     2015-02-04 11:00:00
```

Query to get the first row would be:

```
select * from <tablename> order by time, id limit 1;
```

After this what would be the query to get next row that would be having id value "P002"

Comment: `offset`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I can not use offset here for 2 reasons:    First we can display data in reverse order of time and second data are being added to table randomly.

Comment: Can you please down the query without using offset ?

Comment: If you can _order_ the data properly (which is necessary to be able to correctly use `limit`) then of course you can use `offset`

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would do that with offset, but if there's an index on `time, id` you can do it slightly more efficient for the database (only really noticable if you have millions of rows though).

Standard solution:

```
select * from <tablename>
order by time, id limit 1 offset 1;
```

Indexed (usually faster) solution:

```
select * from <tablename>
where time >= '2015-02-04 10:00:00' and id > 'P001'
order by time, id limit 1;
```